# copying boost::exception across threads crashing

Tags: c++, boost

Below sample code to copy/transfer boost::exception object from 1 thread to another crashes due to a race condition during destruction of exception/exception_ptr internal state. I am not sure what is the best way to resolve it.

The boost version used was 1.42 and platform is Ubuntu lucid running on a dual core Intel m/c. The compiler was gcc 4.4.3.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

struct Exception
    : public virtual std::exception
    , public virtual boost::exception
{
};

struct MyException : public virtual Exception {};

struct MyTag {};

typedef boost::error_info<MyTag, std::string> MyError;

struct Test
{
    Test()
    {
        _t.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Test::executor, this)));
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        _t->join();
    }

    void executor()
    {
        std::cerr << "executor: starting ...\n";
        for (;;)
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_mx);
            while(_q.empty())
            {
                _cv.wait(lk);
            }
            {
                boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<int> > pt = _q.front();
                _q.pop_front();
                lk.unlock();
                pt->set_exception(boost::copy_exception(MyException() << MyError("test")));
            }
        }
    }

    void run_impl()
    {
        try
        {
            boost::shared_ptr< boost::promise<int> > pm(new boost::promise<int>());

            boost::unique_future<int> fu = pm->get_future();
            {
                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_mx);
                _q.push_back(pm);
                pm.reset();
            }
            _cv.notify_one();

            fu.get();
            assert(false);
        }
        catch (const MyException& e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (const boost::exception& )
        {
            assert(false);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::cerr << "run: starting ...\n";
        for (;;)
        {
            try
            {
                run_impl();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
            }
        }
    }

private:

    boost::mutex _mx;
    std::list< boost::shared_ptr< boost::promise<int> > > _q;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> _t;
    boost::condition_variable_any _cv;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.run();
}

/*
#0  0x080526bd in boost::exception_detail::refcount_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_container>::release (this=0x806e26c) at /boost_1_42_0/boost/exception/exception.hpp:79            
#1  0x0804f7c5 in ~refcount_ptr (this=0x806e26c, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /boost_1_42_0/boost/exception/exception.hpp:34                                                           
#2  0x0804bb61 in ~exception (this=0x806e268, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /boost_1_42_0/boost/exception/exception.hpp:254                                                             
#3  0x0805579a in ~clone_impl (this=0x806e260, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>, __vtt_parm=<value optimized out>) at /boost_1_42_0/boost/exception/exception.hpp:391                          
#4  0x001ff633 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6                                                                                                                                                           
#5  0x0027233d in _Unwind_DeleteException () from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1                                                                                                                                           
#6  0x001fe110 in __cxa_end_catch () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6                                                                                                                                              
#7  0x0804f7a4 in Test::run (this=0xbffff74c) at ex_org.cpp:89                                                                                                                                                 
#8  0x0804b869 in main () at ex_org.cpp:106 
*/
```

Comment: What about catching non-references rather than references? So that a local copy is created.

Comment: Doesn't help, still ends up with the same crash.

Comment: Tried to reproduce this using g++ 4.7.0 and boost 1.49 but your example works perfectly fine there (under Arch Linux 3.4.0 on Intel i5)

Comment: I am not sure if anything has changed between boost 1.42 and 1.49 that may have fixed the issue, but the core stack trace indicates a race condition (refcount_ptr destructor) and hence it may appear to run fine for some time. For me also, it runs fine for about 1-2 mins (usually) and then eventually ends up in a seg fault.

Comment: I have been running 5 instances of the program for 40 minutes now, and none of those crashed. Either I got incredibly (un)lucky, or it has been fixed somewhere on the way to the newer versions

Comment: Yes, I have found that the issue was fixed between the boost versions 1.42 - 49. The issue ticket is https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3848, and the change resolving the ticket is  
http://lists.boost.org/boost-commit/2010/01/22088.php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a boost expert but I noticed some race problems, does it runs ok in debug mode ?

For the executor I would write it like this

```
void executor()
{
    std::cerr << "executor: starting ...\n";

    for (;;)
    {            
        _cv.wait(lk);

        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_mx);

        __sync_synchronize (); // Tells the compiler to prevent optimizations

        if ( !_q.empty() ) {                
            boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<int> > pt = _q.front();
            _q.pop_front();
            pt->set_exception(boost::copy_exception(MyException() << MyError("test")));
        }
    }
}
```

as well as

```
void run_impl()
{
    try
    {
        boost::shared_ptr< boost::promise<int> > pm(new boost::promise<int>());

        boost::unique_future<int> fu = pm->get_future();

        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_mx);

            // prevent the compiler from mixing above and below code
            __sync_synchronize ();

            _q.push_back(pm);
            pm.reset();
        }

        _cv.notify_one();

        // This one is the paranoïd's one ;), one must check without ! 
        __sync_synchronize ();

        {
            // since fu must holds an internal reference pm being currently 
            // changed by the other thread !
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(_mx);

            // Then you are assured that everything is coherent at this point
            // the stack frame holding the exception stuffs won't be corrupted

            fu.get();
        }

        assert(false);
    }
```